# How to identify the sender of an event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mouseevent, sender

I have a to-do software application in which I dynamically create each to-do task. I have a checkmark image on each task that when clicked, calls a `MouseLeftButtonDown` event. It works perfectly fine, but I need to identify which task I clicked on. Here's how I'm doing it so far:

```
private void CreateTask() {
    Image checkmarkImage = new Image();
    checkmarkImage.MouseLeftButtonDown += checkmarkPressed;
}
private void CheckmarkPressed(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Pressed");
}
```

Whenever the image is clicked on, the console writes "Pressed". Is there any way for me to identify which specific object called the function? It would be great if I could pass arguments to the `CheckmarkPressed` function like an integer; `tasksAdded` that could identify the specific task from any array. Anyone know how I can do this?

I tried things like `sender.ToString()` or `e.Source` but those just tell me that the sender was an image.

Comment: I can add a dynamic name to it (like `image.Name = "checkbox" + tasksAdded`) but I don't see any way to request the name from the given parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your are using the event handler `CheckmarkPressed` to be called only by the same type of objects, and that you are setting a unique identifier to recognize your objects, like [@Ostas mentioned in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62071256/how-to-identify-the-sender-of-an-event#comment109782429_62071378), you may use the property `Tag` for this purpose `image.Tag = "checkbox" + tasksAdded` (Quoted from your comment):

```
private void CheckmarkPressed(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    var caller = (Image) sender;
    Console.WriteLine("Pressed by{0}",caller.Tag);
}
```

Comment: You could also make use of the Tag property that is an object where you can store anything you want.

Comment: That worked for me! I didn't know I could get the item from the `sender`. Thank you!

Comment: @Ostas interesting I didn't know about that thanks.